# How to get Windows edition?

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to create a script in PowerShell that verifies the OS edition (Pro, Enterprise, Home, etc.). I have found many information about how to verify with an ID number the OS version (Vista, 7, 8, 8.1, etc.), but I can't find anything about the editions codes. My questions are:

1. Are there codes for Windows editions?
2. If there are no codes, and the only way is `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | % Caption`, how can I format this to select the edition on any windows operating system?
3. Are there other ways to do this?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724833(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That information is encoded in the `OperatingSystemSKU` property of the [`Win32_OperatingSystem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class:

```
Value  Meaning
-----  -------
    0  Undefined
    1  Ultimate Edition
    2  Home Basic Edition
    3  Home Premium Edition
    4  Enterprise Edition
    5  Home Basic N Edition
    6  Business Edition
    7  Standard Server Edition
    8  Datacenter Server Edition
    9  Small Business Server Edition
   10  Enterprise Server Edition
   11  Starter Edition
   12  Datacenter Server Core Edition
   13  Standard Server Core Edition
   14  Enterprise Server Core Edition
   15  Enterprise Server Edition for Itanium-Based Systems
   16  Business N Edition
   17  Web Server Edition
   18  Cluster Server Edition
   19  Home Server Edition
   20  Storage Express Server Edition
   21  Storage Standard Server Edition
   22  Storage Workgroup Server Edition
   23  Storage Enterprise Server Edition
   24  Server For Small Business Edition
   25  Small Business Server Premium Edition
   29  Web Server, Server Core
   39  Datacenter Edition without Hyper-V, Server Core
   40  Standard Edition without Hyper-V, Server Core
   41  Enterprise Edition without Hyper-V, Server Core
   42  Hyper-V Server
```

Put the above list in a [hashtable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx) for mapping the integer value to the description:

```psh
$editions = @{
  0  = 'Undefined'
  1  = 'Ultimate Edition'
  2  = 'Home Basic Edition'
  ...
  41 = 'Enterprise Edition without Hyper-V, Server Core'
  42 = 'Hyper-V Server'
}

$sku = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).OperatingSystemSKU

'Edition is {0}.' -f $editions[$sku]
```

Note, however, that `OperatingSystemSKU` is not available on Server 2003 and earlier. On those systems you'll have to check the `Caption` and/or `OSProductSuite` property.

Comment: This will not work, for example I have Windows 10 Pro (number 48), and it's not on the list. not even here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-operatingsystem?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Yep, so where are these hash tables really defined in the Windows OS? Must be a different way to access these. Obviously somewhere in the code spitting out the `OS name`.

Comment: You need to use `CIM` with: `(Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption` or get see if there is anything else more useful: `(Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem) | select *`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use 'Get-WindowsEdition -online'.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/get-windowsedition

Comment: Unfortunately, this is only available as *admin*, otherwise you get permission error: `Get-WindowsEdition: The requested operation requires elevation.` Also, it doesn't really tell you the *public* version you expect, instead for *Windows Home* edition, it says `Core`, which is a totally useless result.

Comment: Although I haven't tried it on window home, my Windows 11 Pro does return  "Edition: Professional".

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
Get-ComputerInfo | select WindowsProductName, OsOperatingSystemSKU, OsName | fl

# <output>
# WindowsProductName   : Windows 10 Home
# OsOperatingSystemSKU : WindowsHome
# OsName               : Microsoft Windows 10 Home
```

If you want other items, look in the list from:

```
# (Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem) | select *

Status                                    : OK
Name                                      : <rest is redacted>
FreePhysicalMemory                        :
FreeSpaceInPagingFiles                    :
FreeVirtualMemory                         :
Caption                                   :
Description                               :
InstallDate                               :
CreationClassName                         :
CSCreationClassName                       :
CSName                                    :
CurrentTimeZone                           :
Distributed                               :
LastBootUpTime                            :
LocalDateTime                             :
MaxNumberOfProcesses                      :
MaxProcessMemorySize                      :
NumberOfLicensedUsers                     :
NumberOfProcesses                         :
NumberOfUsers                             :
OSType                                    :
OtherTypeDescription                      :
SizeStoredInPagingFiles                   :
TotalSwapSpaceSize                        :
TotalVirtualMemorySize                    :
TotalVisibleMemorySize                    :
Version                                   :
BootDevice                                :
BuildNumber                               :
BuildType                                 :
CodeSet                                   :
CountryCode                               :
CSDVersion                                :
DataExecutionPrevention_32BitApplications :
DataExecutionPrevention_Available         :
DataExecutionPrevention_Drivers           :
DataExecutionPrevention_SupportPolicy     :
Debug                                     :
EncryptionLevel                           :
ForegroundApplicationBoost                :
LargeSystemCache                          :
Locale                                    :
Manufacturer                              :
MUILanguages                              :
OperatingSystemSKU                        :
Organization                              :
OSArchitecture                            :
OSLanguage                                :
OSProductSuite                            :
PAEEnabled                                :
PlusProductID                             :
PlusVersionNumber                         :
PortableOperatingSystem                   :
Primary                                   :
ProductType                               :
RegisteredUser                            :
SerialNumber                              :
ServicePackMajorVersion                   :
ServicePackMinorVersion                   :
SuiteMask                                 :
SystemDevice                              :
SystemDirectory                           :
SystemDrive                               :
WindowsDirectory                          :
PSComputerName                            :
CimClass                                  :
CimInstanceProperties                     :
CimSystemProperties                       :
```

Comment: `Get-ComputerInfo` is a bit slow for my taste...

Comment: @Dennis Indeed, it's useless if you need quick scriptable info. I think it first collects a huge blob of info and then filters that blob according to your command-line parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I usually run something like this for Windows 10.  You can also see what monthly update you're at from the ubr.

```
# vercheck.ps1
$reg = Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion'
$releaseid = $reg.releaseid
$ubr = $reg.ubr
$displayversion = $reg.displayversion

[pscustomobject]@{
  releaseid = $releaseid
  displayversion = $displayversion
  ubr = $ubr
}
```

```
releaseid displayversion  ubr
--------- --------------  ---
2009      21H2           2251
```