# Determine whether the current computer supports Group Policy

Tags: .net, windows, group-policy

My .NET application needs to set some Group Policy settings in the local GPO and have them applied to the Registry. On some editions of Windows (e.g. Pro and Enterprise), adjusting the local GPO and invoking [`RefreshPolicyEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374401(v=vs.85).aspx) is sufficient - Windows handles the application of the POL data to the Registry. On editions that do not support Group Policy, my program does the Registry adjustment itself. It would be bad if my program did that on GP-enabled editions because that would interfere with Windows's bookkeeping.

Therefore, I need a way to reliably tell whether the current Windows machine is capable of applying a local Group Policy Object. Checking for the existence of `gpedit.msc` or `secpol.msc` works on most machines, but some users run [this script](https://www.itechtics.com/easily-enable-group-policy-editor-gpedit-msc-in-windows-10-home-edition/) which partially installs the Group Policy infrastructure on Home editions - just enough to confuse my program but not enough to actually make Windows do the Registry adjustments. Having a [table of SKUs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30705839/2825369) would work for all currently existing editions, but [as seen on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724358(v=vs.85).aspx), Windows 10 introduced many new codes and I would prefer to not have to worry about continually maintaining a table. Finally, I could check for things like "Home" or "Starter" in the OS `Caption` returned [by WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239(v=vs.85).aspx), but that also seems brittle.

How can I most reliably determine whether the current Windows installation can apply Group Policy?